# How to capture the result of salt's execution module in SLS?

Tags: salt-stack

```
{% testVar = pillar['ServiceName'] %}

GetServiceId:
  module.run:
    - service.getsid:
      - name: testVar
   

useServiceId:
  - cmd.script:
    - source: test/path/test.ps1
    - args:
```

According to the doc https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.win_service.html#salt.modules.win_service.get_service_name , the execution module returns a string. How can I capture the string returned by "GetServiceId" and use it in "useServiceId"?

Comment: Note that your jinja is also invalid - `{% testvar %}` is not a valid tag, and the `name: testVar` is passing the literal string `"testVar"`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, depending on which stage of the process the module should run.

During rendering (preferred):

```yaml
useServiceId:
  - cmd.script:
    - source: salt://test/path/test.ps1
    - args: "{{ salt["service.getsid"](pillar["ServiceName"]) }}"
```

During execution:

```yaml
useServiceId:
  - cmd.script:
    - source: salt://test/path/test.ps1
    - args: __slot__:salt:service.getsid({{ pillar["ServiceName"] }})
```

Note: assuming that the service name isn't secret in any way, it probably shouldn't be in pillar, and instead be loaded from some sort of `map.jinja` or `variables.yaml` in the state tree.